# Building the services samples AllJoyn Thin Client on Linux

Tags: linux, service, alljoyn, thin-client

I have tried to build the service samples AllJoyn Thin Client on Linux but I'm getting an error. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem ?

I have searched some solutions but I couldn't find any answer that fit into my problem.

The prompt returns this message: ALLJOYN_DISTDIR variable is required.

More information can be observed on the image:
[AllJoyn Thin Client Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NctEW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare an environment variable called `ALLJOYN_DISTDIR` with the location of the built libraries.

For instance, for the linux x86:

```
ALLJOYN_DISTDIR=/home/username/alljoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/dist/cpp/lib
```

Comment: @Alexsander Caproni make sense?

Comment: It's necessary to add "export" before ALLJOYN_DISTDIR. Then: 
export ALLJOYN_DISTDIR=/home/username/alljoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/dist/cpp/lib

Answer (score 0):

After creating the variable, I had another problem compiling the service samples. The problem is probably in one file called Debug.h, which is missing.

The prompt returns this message: Service.h:20:23: fatal error: qcc/Debug.h: No such file or directory.

More information can be observed on the image: [Debug.h error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drsVq.png)